# Percentage Puzzle question

Tags: number-sequence

There are two groups A and B with a value of 100 each.
At the end of every day, group A gives 20% of it to group B while group B simultaneously gives 10 % of it to group A.

So at the end of day 1, group A has 90 (100-20+10) while group B has 110 (100+20-10).
At the end of day 2, these values would be 83 for group A and 117 for group B.

What would the values of the groups be after n days?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fact that there are only two groups, and the fact that they are giving hypothetical things to each other only.

Since they only have $200$ things between them, then at any moment, if Group $A$ has $a_i$ things, then Group $B$ has $200-a_i$ things, so we can remove a variable (the amount Group $B$ has).

If $a_i$ denotes the number of things Group $A$ has at the end of day $i$ $(i\geq 0)$, then by the conditions of the problem, $a_{i+1}=a_i-0.2(a_i)+0.1(200-a_i)=0.7a_i+20$.

(For $i=0$, the interpretation of this is the starting amount, despite the lack of an official "Day 0" in the problem statement. It's "the amount at the beginning of Day 1.")

This is called a first order linear recurrence, whose summation's general formula can be proven via induction if necessary, but writing out a few terms should also make the pattern clear:

$a_1=0.7a_0+20$

$a_2=0.7a_1+20=0.7^2a_0+(0.7)(20)+20$

$a_3=0.7a_2+20=0.7^3a_0+(0.7)^2(20)+(0.7)(20)+20$

$a_n=(0.7)^na_0+20\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(0.7)^i$

And some more algebra later using $a_0=100$ and the formula for sum of a finite geometric series:

$a_n=\frac{100}{3}(0.7)^n+\frac{200}{3}$ (and Group $B$ just has $200-a_n$).

This is verified by Quark's output; as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $a_n\rightarrow\frac{200}{3}=66.666\dots$ since $(0.7)^n\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the sequence looks like:

```
1:  a = 90.000000       b=110.000000
2:  a = 83.000000       b=117.000000
3:  a = 78.099998       b=121.900002
4:  a = 74.669998       b=125.330002
5:  a = 72.268997       b=127.731003
6:  a = 70.588295       b=129.411697
7:  a = 69.411804       b=130.588181
8:  a = 68.588264       b=131.411728
9:  a = 68.011780       b=131.988205
10:  a = 67.608246      b=132.391739
11:  a = 67.325768      b=132.674210
12:  a = 67.128036      b=132.871948
13:  a = 66.989624      b=133.010361
14:  a = 66.892738      b=133.107254
15:  a = 66.824913      b=133.175079
16:  a = 66.777435      b=133.222549
17:  a = 66.744202      b=133.255783
18:  a = 66.720940      b=133.279053
19:  a = 66.704659      b=133.295334
20:  a = 66.693260      b=133.306732
21:  a = 66.685280      b=133.314713
22:  a = 66.679695      b=133.320297
23:  a = 66.675781      b=133.324203
24:  a = 66.673042      b=133.326935
25:  a = 66.671127      b=133.328857
26:  a = 66.669785      b=133.330200
27:  a = 66.668846      b=133.331131
28:  a = 66.668190      b=133.331787
29:  a = 66.667732      b=133.332245
30:  a = 66.667412      b=133.332565
31:  a = 66.667183      b=133.332794
32:  a = 66.667023      b=133.332947
33:  a = 66.666916      b=133.333054
34:  a = 66.666840      b=133.333130
35:  a = 66.666786      b=133.333191
36:  a = 66.666748      b=133.333221
37:  a = 66.666718      b=133.333252
38:  a = 66.666702      b=133.333267
39:  a = 66.666687      b=133.333282
40:  a = 66.666679      b=133.333298
41:  a = 66.666672      b=133.333298
42:  a = 66.666672      b=133.333298
```

Here's the code to produce this list:

```
/* Author: Quark */
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a = 100;
    float b = 100;
    float temp_a, temp_b;
    int count = 1;

    while(1){
        temp_a=a*0.2;
        temp_b=b*0.1;
        a=a-temp_a+temp_b;
        b=b-temp_b+temp_a;
        printf("%d:  a = %f\tb=%f\n", count, a, b);
        count++;
    }
}
```